# @Html.DropDownList not binding selectedValue in Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4, DropdownList is not binding SelectedValue. Please find my code below , I did not understand where it went wrong.

I have seen the SelectList , It has SelectedValue but not binding it in View DropdownList

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Employee model = _unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Find(id);
            ViewBag.OfficeSiteId = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.OfficeSiteRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name", model.OfficeSiteId);
return View("Edit", model);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="control-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId, new {@class = "control-label"})

                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownList("OfficeSiteId", ViewBag.OfficeSiteId as SelectList,  new {@class = "chzn-select"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId, null, new {@class = "help-inline"})
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Html.DropDownList("OfficeSiteId",null,new {@class = "chzn-select"})

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId,
    ViewBag.OfficeSiteId as SelectList,  new {@class = "chzn-select"})
```

in place of:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OfficeSiteId",
    ViewBag.OfficeSiteId as SelectList,  new {@class = "chzn-select"})
```

**AND**

Write:

```
ViewBag.OfficeSiteId = new SelectList(
    _unitOfWork.OfficeSiteRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name");
```

in place of:

```
ViewBag.OfficeSiteId = new SelectList(
    _unitOfWork.OfficeSiteRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name", model.OfficeSiteId);
```

Comment: we have both DropDownList and DropDownListFor , i want to use DropDownList  and also if I pass ViewBag.OfficeSiteId = new SelectList(_unitOfWork.OfficeSiteRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name"); nothing will be selected from my Edit model Action

Answer (score 0):

Your action method is OK. Just change your view like the following:

```
<div class="control-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId, new {@class = "control-label"})

     <div class="controls">
          @Html.DropDownList("OfficeSiteId", String.Empty)

          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId)
     </div>
</div>
```

and if you need to set the `class` attribute, use the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId, 
   new SelectList(new PtDbContext().OfficeSites, "ID", "Name"),
   htmlAttributes: new { class = "yourClass" })
```

or if you send the selectList by ViewBag:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OfficeSiteId, 
    (SelectList)ViewBag.OfficeSiteId,
     htmlAttributes: new { class = "yourClass" })
```

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("OfficeSiteId", String.Empty,  new {class = "chzn-select"}) this is wrong , compile error ,  If I  write     @Html.DropDownList("OfficeSiteId", ViewBag.OfficeSiteId as SelectList,String.Emplike this , nothing is selected in dropdlown, I need to get selcted model.OfficeSiteid value

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I've editted my answer code... That will works

Comment: but how can I pass the class name new {@class = "chzn-select"}